# How to separate different textboxes in a control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

I have three `Textboxes` that I don't know how to separate from each others to get the correct value. I Create the `Textboxes` in `GetTrix();` and when I try to update the **value** the **values** are wrong because there's no difference between them.

```
    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string TrixName = null;
    string TrixID = null;
    string Hardness = null;
    string Webpage = null;

    foreach (Control c in phdTrix.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        {
            //This is where there is no difference between the textboxes

            TrixName = (c as TextBox).Text;
            TrixID = (c as TextBox).ID;
            Hardness = (c as TextBox).Text;
            Webpage = (c as TextBox).Text;

            UpdateTrix(TrixID, TrixName, Hardness, Webpage);
        }
    }
}

private void GetTrix()
{
    DataTable table = CategoryAccess.GetAllTrix();

    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
        textbox.ID = table.Rows[i]["TrixID"].ToString();
        textbox.Text = table.Rows[i]["TrixName"].ToString();

        Literal literal1 = new Literal();
        literal1.Text = "<p>";

        TextBox textbox2 = new TextBox();
        textbox2.Text = table.Rows[i]["Hardness"].ToString();

        TextBox textbox3 = new TextBox();
        textbox3.Text = table.Rows[i]["Webpage"].ToString();

        Literal literal2 = new Literal();
        literal2.Text = "</p>";

        phdTrix.Controls.Add(literal1);
        phdTrix.Controls.Add(textbox);
        phdTrix.Controls.Add(textbox2);
        phdTrix.Controls.Add(textbox3);
        phdTrix.Controls.Add(literal2);
    }
}
```

This would be a logic solution. But dosent work.

```
TrixName = (c as TextBox textbox).Text; 
Hardness = (c as TextBox textbox2).Text;
Webpage = (c as TextBox textbox3).Text;
```

The new code:

```
    protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string TrixID = null;
    string TrixName = null;
    string Hardness = null;
    string Webpage = null;

    foreach (Control c in phdTrix.Controls)
    {
        if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        {
            TrixID = (c as Literal).Text;

            switch (c.ID)
            {

                case "TrixName":
                    TrixName = (c as TextBox).Text;
                    break;
                case "Hardness":
                    Hardness = (c as TextBox).Text;
                    break;
                case "Webpage":
                    Webpage = (c as TextBox).Text;
                    break;
            }

            UpdateTrix(TrixID, TrixName, Hardness, Webpage);
        }
    }
}



private void GetTrix()
{
    DataTable table = CategoryAccess.GetAllTrix();

    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        Literal literalTrixID = new Literal();
        literalTrixID.Text = table.Rows[i]["TrixID"].ToString();
        literalTrixID.Visible = false;

        TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
        textbox.ID = "TrixName";
        textbox.Text = table.Rows[i]["TrixName"].ToString();

        Literal literal1 = new Literal();
        literal1.Text = "<p>";

        TextBox textbox2 = new TextBox();
        textbox2.ID = "Hardness";
        textbox2.Text = table.Rows[i]["Hardness"].ToString();

        TextBox textbox3 = new TextBox();
        textbox3.ID = "Webpage";
        textbox3.Text = table.Rows[i]["Webpage"].ToString();

        Literal literal2 = new Literal();
        literal2.Text = "</p>";

        phdTrix.Controls.Add(literalTrixID);
        phdTrix.Controls.Add(literal1);
        phdTrix.Controls.Add(textbox);
        phdTrix.Controls.Add(textbox2);
        phdTrix.Controls.Add(textbox3);
        phdTrix.Controls.Add(literal2);
    }
}
```

I get an error: Several control's with the same ID (`TrixName`) were found. `FindControl` have to have a Unique ID.

Answer (score 4):

Well there won't be.

You are looping over the controls `foreach (Control c in phdTrix.Controls)` and **each time** you find a text box you are doing the following:

```
        TrixName = (c as TextBox).Text;
        Hardness = (c as TextBox).Text;
        Webpage = (c as TextBox).Text;
```

This will assign the same text box to each variable.

The simplest solution is to assign a unique identifier to each text box when you create it and then use that to determine which one you want. You can use the [`ID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id.aspx) property. Then you can have something like this:

```
string TrixName = null;
string Hardness = null;
string Webpage = null;

foreach (Control c in phdTrix.Controls)
{
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
    {
        switch (c.ID)
        {
            case "TrixName":
                TrixName = (c as TextBox).Text;
                break;
            case "Hardness":
                Hardness = (c as TextBox).Text;
                break;
            case "Webpage":
                Webpage = (c as TextBox).Text;
                break;
        }

        UpdateTrix(TrixID, TrixName, Hardness, Webpage);
    }
}
```

Your creation code needs to be:

```
    TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
    textbox.ID = "TrixName";
    textbox.Text = table.Rows[i]["TrixName"].ToString();

    TextBox textbox2 = new TextBox();
    textbox2.ID = "Hardness";
    textbox2.Text = table.Rows[i]["Hardness"].ToString();

    TextBox textbox3 = new TextBox();
    textbox3.ID = "Webpage";
    textbox3.Text = table.Rows[i]["Webpage"].ToString();
```

You'll need some other way of storing the `TrixID` as you have to have a deterministic way of identifying the controls when you come to read the data out.

However, if you have several groups of these controls on a page this isn't going to work as each ID needs to be unique. In this case you'll need to append a unique id (GUID) on to the controls as you create them:

```
textbox.ID = "TrixName_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

then when you want to find the control use `string.Split()` to strip off the GUID:

```
string[] nameParts = c.ID.Split('_');
switch (nameParts[0])
{
    .... as before.
}
```

Comment: I use an ID on the first one: textbox.ID = table.Rows[i]["TrixID"].ToString(); But how dose that make a diffrens if I dont change TrixName = (c as TextBox).Text;

Comment: Thanks, but I cant get it to work I did put the TrixID into an litteral instead. I edited my question whith my new code.

Comment: Thanks for your time, Im sure it works, but I think I'm putting the textboxes in diffrent placeholders instead then theres no problem to make sure its the right one, becouse there is only one in each placeholder.